# Difference in the HTTP Response code is getting observed when executing a POST call from cURL vs Postman for the same negative test condition

Tags: rest, curl, postman, rest-assured

Correct URI: `https://example.com/a/b/users/111/c`

Negative test URI: `https://example.com/a/b/users/<111>/c`

Sample Request Body:

```
{
    "abc": "xyz"
}
```

Postman returned 404 with a message that the user doesn't exist, for the negative test URI mentioned above.

Then I executed the cURL generated by the Postman and appended to it "-k" to ignore the certificate verification and "-v" for verbosity. However, cURL returned 500 for the same URI.

The original concern was that there has been a mismatch in the test results when the above API was hit by an automation test using RestAssured vs when manually executing it from Postman. Debugging that has led me to find out the difference in response between Postman and curl as well.

Any thoughts to debug this issue further?

[image: Request Body]

[image: Postman Headers]

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of postman with request headers and body. Also please share all the relevant details for cURL request as well.

Comment: Sure.
`curl --location --request POST 'https://example.com/a/b/users/<111>/c' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Authorization: Bearer token' -d '{
    "abc": "xyz"
}' -v -k`

Comment: I have added the screenshots in the question.

Comment: Why does your postman request have two different `content-type` headers? And can you try exporting your request from postman as curl and running exactly that exported command?

Comment: @derpirscher
I tried with a single `content-type`:`application/json` and still got same response from Postman.
Then, I exported curl from Postman and ran that command. 
This curl had `--data-raw` for request body which threw the error `curl: option --data-raw: is unknown` so I changed it to `-d`. Rest I didn't change anything else. 
Then it complained `..the certificate verification probably failed..` and to go around that I added `-k` to the curl as suggested in the error. Again the response mismatched.
Finally I appended `-v` to get more details and it responded with 500 response code.

Comment: What system are you on? And what shell are you executing your `curl` command in? If you are on windows cmd, it might not correctly interpret the json data. CMD is quite picky about quotes. And if you have access to the server, you might want to check the request on the server. Because generally 5xx indicates an error of the server which is not handled correctly (for instance an uncaught exception with json parsing or something like that) ...

Comment: I am running cURL from a linux VM. This application is also running on the docker on the VM. So when I execute the call from Postman, the debugger stops on the breakpoints that I added and eventually returns 404. But in case of cURL, it doesn't even hit the codebase and responds with 500.

Comment: Is there any proxy in between? Because a 500 Error has to come somewhere from a server. Did you set the breakpoint in that specific endpoint? The server is probably failing prior to hitting that endpoint. Can you (for testing purposes) add something that will be hit before any processing and routing? And then compare the two requests? Or if there is no proxy, maybe you can add one and inspect the requests there?

Comment: Does the cURL request return the expected 404 when instead of `<111>` you use some unknown id, that doesn't have the `< >`? For instance `.../users/111111111/c` if there is no such userid ... And also the `--verbose` should output more than just "statuscode 500" in the response ... Ie, it should output also the full request

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240791/discussion-between-jasvinder-singh-and-derpirscher).

Comment: I have found something interesting. When hitting from cURL with <111> in the URI, it lands in an exception with the cause `java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index..`
However, from Postman, the same request goes to find that user. Just some headway that I could make.

Comment: curl has nothing in java so clearly that exception is reached outside of (before?) curl

Comment: @derpirscher While debugging, I found the URI passed was getting encoded and decoded, and `<111>` got printed as `%3C111%3E` at one of the breakpoints. So when I tried sending the encoded URI from cURL like https://example.com/a/b/users/%3C111%3E/c it worked just fine returning 404. However Postman returned 404 both with <111> and %3C111%3E. So you were right that may be shell has been doing something while interpreting the URI.
But my original issue is still failing - that I am seeing different response with Postman vs RestAssured, which I am debugging further. Thanks a lot for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

While debugging, I found the URI passed was getting encoded and decoded, and `<111>` got printed as `%3C111%3E` at one of the breakpoints. So when I tried sending the encoded URI from cURL like `https://example.com/a/b/users/%3C111%3E/c` it worked just fine returning 404. However Postman returned 404 both with `<111>` and `%3C111%3E`.

Thanks to @derpirscher for providing hints that helped me reach this conclusion.

P.S. For more details, please refer my last comment above.